# incompatible index of inserted column with frame index with group by and count

Tags: pandas, indexing, group-by, count

I have data that looks like this:

```
CHROM    POS REF ALT  ...  is_sever_int is_sever_str is_sever_f encoding_str
0  chr1  14907   A   G  ...             1            1        one          one
1  chr1  14930   A   G  ...             1            1        one          one
```

These are the columns that I'm interested to perform calculations on (example) :

```
is_severe       snp _id            encoding 

       1             1                   one
       1             1                    two
       0             1                    one
       1             2                     two
       0             2                      two
       0             2                       one
```

what I want to do is to count for each snp_id and severe_id how many ones and twos are in the encoding column :

```
snp_id        is_svere       encoding_one         encoding_two
  1               1             1                        1
  1               0             1                        0
  2                1             0                       1
  2                0            1                         1
```

I tried this :

```
df.groupby(["snp_id","is_sever_f","encoding_str"])["encoding_str"].count()
```

but it gave the error :

```
 incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

then i tried this:

```
df["count"]=df.groupby(["snp_id","is_sever_f","encoding_str"],as_index=False)["encoding_str"].count()
```

and it returned:

```
Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (2532831, 3)
```

how can i fix this? thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `groupby` with whole columns and get size of each group then `unstack` the `encoding` index.

```py
out = (df.groupby(['is_severe', 'snp_id', 'encoding']).size()
       .unstack(fill_value=0)
       .add_prefix('encoding_')
       .reset_index())
```

```
print(out)

encoding  is_severe  snp_id  encoding_one  encoding_two
0                 0       1             1             0
1                 0       2             1             1
2                 1       1             1             1
3                 1       2             0             1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try as follows:

- Use [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) to convert categorical data in column `encoding` into indicator variables.
- Chain [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and get `sum` to turn double rows per group into one row (i.e. `[0,1]` and `[1,0]` will become `[1,1]` where `df.snp_id == 2` and `df.is_severe == 0`).

```
res = pd.get_dummies(data=df, columns=['encoding'])\
    .groupby(['snp_id','is_severe'], as_index=False, sort=False).sum()
    
print(res)

   snp_id  is_severe  encoding_one  encoding_two
0       1          1             1             1
1       1          0             1             0
2       2          1             0             1
3       2          0             1             1
```

---

If your actual `df` has more columns, limit the assigment to the `data` parameter inside `get_dummies`. I.e. use:

```
res = pd.get_dummies(data=df[['is_severe', 'snp_id', 'encoding']], 
                     columns=['encoding']).groupby(['snp_id','is_severe'], 
                                                   as_index=False, sort=False)\
                                                   .sum()
```

Comment: it changes the whole data frame and starts summing up all the columns .

Comment: I'm assuming you mean that the actual `df` has many more columns? Limit the assignment to the `data` parameter. I.e. use: `pd.get_dummies(data=df[['snp_id','is_severe','encoding']], ...)` etc. Alternatively, at the end use: `sort=False)[['encoding_one','encoding_two']].sum()`